# Could not create directory '/c/\303\234/.ssh'

Tags: git, windows-7, ssh, push, tortoisegit

I have created an OpenShift application using rhc. The git repository has been cloned successfully on my Windows 7 PC. I want to push my code changes back to OpenShift. I am using TortoiseGit.

I have used the procedure described [here](http://olelynge.blogspot.nl/2012/04/tortoisegit-and-ssh-keys.html) to create and set SSH keys for TortoiseGit. I have modified the settings to configure the SSH private key:

[image]

Yet, when I try to push my changes, I get:

[image]

What is causing this and how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Everyone how has this issue - first check your system profile path for non latin (cyrillic etc) characters. c:\User\Ваня - is bad, shoud be c:\User\vanya. Then set HOME variable as described below. I spent a day to figure this out :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like git cannot save the known hosts list on `c:\` (in `c:\.ssh\.known_hosts`). Usually the `.ssh` dir is being created in the $HOME directory. Try setting the HOME environment variable to a directory writable by the current user, i.e. the user's home directory in Windows: `c:\Users\<username>`.

It depends whether you're using msysgit or installed git through cygwin, etc. Please take a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-to-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key for further information.

Comment: I checked my environment variables and noticed I did not have a $HOME entry. I created one and pointed at: c:\User\MyUserName. I tried to push my changes with TortoiseSVN again and it worked like a charm. Many thanks.