# Could not create directory '/home/username/.ssh'

Tags: windows, bash, git, ssh

Git suddenly stopped working for me. (I use Git Bash under Windows 7. I am not using Cygwin.)

Every time I try to pull or push it says:

```
Could not create directory '/home/sigod/.ssh'
```

My SSH keys located in `C:\Users\sigod\.ssh` and `HOME` set to `/c/Users/sigod`. Which should work according to [various](https://serverfault.com/a/198691) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14538440/944911) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2840909/944911).

If I place SSH keys into `C:\Program Files\Git\home\sigod\.ssh` then Git starts working again. But how can I make it work without dirty solutions?

Comment: Do you use Cygwin?

Comment: @mauro, no, I don't.

Comment: As a temporary solution I created symlink for `c:\Program Files\Git\home\ <<===>> c:\Users`.

Comment: `mkdir /home/sigod/.ssh` might help

Comment: Same problem with me. Has anyone a solution, yet?

Comment: Git should be using your home directory, which should be configured by the operating system. Presumably `/home/sigod` does not exist (or is not a directory), but something in your environment is telling git that that's your home directory. Even under Linux, the home directory for user `sigod` is not necessarily `/home/sigod`; the home directory for a user is set by the entry in `/etc/passwd`, which is used to set the `$HOME` environment variable, which is what git looks at. It probably works differently under Windows. Perhaps a Windows expert can help.

Answer (score 11):

Git Bash is built using MSYS2, [which is a very close cousin to CygWin](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/How-does-MSYS2-differ-from-Cygwin/). The following steps might just work for your case:

1. Open cmd.exe as administrator, and set the **HOME** system environment variable to point to your user directory.

   ```
   setx -m HOME ^%UserProfile^%
   ```

The above command will set **HOME=%UserProfile%** for your system environment.

2. Open git bash, and make sure that **/etc/nsswitch.conf** file contains an uncommented **db_home** line entry. Make sure it matches one of the below configurations:

   **option a:**

   ```
   db_home: env windows cygwin desc
   ```

   **option b:**

   ```
   db_home: windows
   ```
3. Fully close git-bash when trying out options in step 2 (to be sure no background processes are keeping git-bash alive, log off from windows and log back in).

I based the above on an answer explaining the [CygWin version of the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1494721).

Comment: thanks for the correction. modified my answer. btw https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 1):

GitBash is similar to Cygwin which uses traditional linux permissions.

I suggest you make sure your ssh directory exists in the correct place and has the right permissions by running from git bash the following commands:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chown $USER:$USER -R ~/.ssh
```

then run `stat ~/.ssh` to see that the permissions changed correctly

```
ls ~/.ssh
```

to see that your key is properly installed in the correct place.

You can see which directory is actually registered as your home directory by running `echo ~` or `echo $HOME`.

You can change your linux HOME by modifying `~/.bashrc` and adding the line `export HOME=/some/directory`

You can see how your GitBash filesystem corresponds to your windows filesystem by typing the command `mount`

```
MINGW64 /c $ mount
C:/Program Files/Git on / type ntfs (binary,noacl,auto)
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin on /bin type ntfs (binary,noacl,auto)
C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/Temp on /tmp type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,usertemp)
C: on /c type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
D: on /d type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

---

If nothing else works, you can also try modifying the `%HOME%` environment variable in windows to make sure it directs to the right path. But any windows env var will be overwritten by linux vars you add to your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thank you for detailed response. Unfortunately, I cannot test it, as the problem disappeared along with symlink.

Comment: In my case the owner was correct but there was a permissions issue. A blanket `chmod -R 777 .ssh` fixed the issue (and a subsequent issue with writing to the known_hosts file) - but would of course strongly recommend taking a backup of the existing `.ssh` folder for anyone doing this.

Comment: @SteveChambers hi, thanks for bringing this issue to my attention. I would strongly advise *against* chmod -R 777 .ssh as this enables any visitor or guest to your computer to see your private ssh keys.

Instead I would simply add -R to my command to make it recursive. I've update my answer to reflect this. 

Regarding the permissions in your .ssh folder I suggest running `chown $USER:$USER -R ~/.ssh` to make yourself the owner and fixing the permissions with :
`chmod 644 -R ~/.ssh`  
`chmod 700 ~/.ssh`
`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure which one [ssh.exe] you are executing ! $ where ssh

```
D:\xxxx\bin\ssh.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
```

In my case, there is another ssh.exe in my export Path. (i.e.: D:\xxxx\bin\ssh.exe)

So I remove the the ssh.exe and keep the original one! (C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe)

Everything is nice now!

Answer (score 1):

***Windows Machine***

you can use *cd ~/.ssh/* instead of *~/.ssh*

```
cd ~/.ssh/
```

Comment: What difference would that make? What does this have to do with the question being asked?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: no need to create the .ssh folder. by default, it has on windows or any other os, in Windows you just type ~/.ssh, will get an error. if you change the directory cd ~/.ssh/, it will navigate to .ssh folder on your machine

Comment: that so wierd i run 'ls -al' but not showing .ssh but if  run cd ~/.ssh/ then enter .ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here: Could not create directory '/home/carlos.leao/.ssh', in Git Bash for Windows, version 2.17.1.2-64-bit. Using Windows 10.

Solve with sigod workaround. But insted of create the folder struture C:\Program Files\Git\home\carlos.leao and copied the folder C:\Users\carlos.leao.ssh into it i've created a symbolic link from C:\Users\carlos.leao.ssh to C:\Program Files\Git\home\carlos.leao.ssh. To do it (replace carlos.leao with your Windows username):

1. Create this folder struture C:\Program Files\Git**home\carlos.leao**
2. start CMD.exe
3. run the comand: mklink /d "C:\Users\carlos.leao.ssh" "C:\Program Files\Git\home\carlos.leao.ssh"

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling git-bash worked for me.